# AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'getsource' using Textmate

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, textmate, shebang

This used to work in Textmate

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from forecastiopy import *
```

Recently it stopped working only if the file is saved, the same code works in an unsaved file. (I must've messed it up somehow, but I'm not sure how to fix it). Any help is greatly appreciated.

python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3 & /usr/local/bin is in Textmate's PATH

macOS Mojave 10.14.2
Python 3.7.2
TextMate 2.0-rc.10

Comment: Please add some more details? What platform? Python version?

Comment: Are you running this as a command, or are you saving the file somewhere else? Does it work in a terminal if you do `$ python3 -i` and enter `>>> from forecastiopy import *`?

Comment: I'm pressing cmd+R from within Textmate and it works in Terminal using python3 -i

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed it. I had a user sample script called inspect.py which was using the inspect module in the same directory which was being imported instead of the actual module.